# Best way to store one large text resources iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am super new to iOS(like I just finished hello world) and I have a large text(1.5k words) file that I would like to show in a modal dialog in my application.

However, I am confused on the best way to store this static text file and load it at runtime. Any help and links would be appreciated.

I see people use .plist, but apparently that is loaded into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use static texts the best way is to do it taking localization into account from the beginning.
Here is a link from Apple Developer showing you how to do it, including how to store strings in a file and loading them into your application.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000277-SW1

Comment: This doesn't really show me how to get a string from the .strings file, could you help me out with that?

Comment: The way to do that is by using the `NSLocalizedString(@"A String Identifier", @"A String choice if no identifier is found")`.  So you write something like `"A String identifier" = "A lot of text that will display every time I call NSLocalizedString(string, nil)";` in the Localizable.strings file.